# background-image not showing in div normally or on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Ok guys, I have this in the style.css of my website.

```
 .asia{
margin-left:40px;
background-image:url('../resources/img/asia.jpg');
width:100px;
height:75px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
 }
.asia:hover{
background-image:url('../resources/img/asia2.png');
width:100px;
height:75px;

 }
```

these are two images, that I will use on my homepage by putting

```
<div class="asia"></div>
```

and everything is set for them to show up like an animation when hovering over.

The only problem is that on the laptop everything works fine, the index.html shows me all the images and the hover efect works well but when uploading and testing it on the server the images do not show up.

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure you did upload the images also? May I take a look to the "live" site?

Comment: Your code is correct, as I just tried it. I would make sure you uploaded the images to your server and that the paths to the files are correct.

Comment: Still not working, I don't understand what the problem is because the image paths are CORRECT.

Comment: css file is uploaded?  what is the site url? did you try with an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Could I make a suggestion, instead of having two files, perhaps combine them into one image. 
Then, on hover you can update the `background-position`. This way, your document won't need to request another file from the server (good for people on mobile, and conserving downloads) as well as preventing a 'flicker' while the page hangs without its file and loads it in. Here's an example of the implementation.

```
.imageContainer {
   background: url('../resources/img/asiacombined.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Let's assume the image is 100px tall.

```
.imageContainer:hover { 
   background-position: 50px /*x axis, shifting to the top of the next image in the file*/ 0 /* Y axis */;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Ps.

You can also use `top`, `left`, `right`, `center`, `bottom` to align content.

Comment: Still not working, I don't understand what the problem is because the image paths are CORRECT.

Comment: Alright. This might be annoying, but let's try this. Start with changing your css img url's to two new files hosted on Google, for example. Then upload your Page to your server and try again. If those images come up, with no problem I believe this would indicate that something is up with your file path. This should help us narrow down the answer.

Comment: I tried your solution and it still doesn't work, it's not the path, something else must be wrong.

Comment: Any chance that you could post the URL to your website? I'm stumped. In the meantime, what happens if you take the transition off - does the result change?